# Only select from tables that are of interest

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, database-performance, dynamicquery

**SQL Server 2016**

I have a number of tables

```
Table A             Table B              Table C                 Table D
 User | DataA        User | DataB         User | DataC            User | DataD
 ===========         ===========          ===================     =============
 1    | 10            1   |  'hello'        4  | '2020-01-01'     1    | 0.34
 2    | 20            2   |  'world'       
 3    | 30
```

So some users have data for `A`,`B`,`C` and/or `D`.

```
Table UserEnabled            
 User  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  
 =============================
  1    |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
  2    |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
  3    |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0
  4    |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0
```

Table `UserEnabled` indicates whether we are interested in any of the data in the corresponding tables `A`,`B`,`C` and/or `D`.

Now I want to join those tables on `User` but I do only want the columns where the `UserEnabled` table has at least one user with a 1 (ie at least one user enabled). Ideally I only want to join the tables that are enabled and not filter the columns from the disabled tables afterwards.

So as a result for all users I would get

```
User | DataA |  DataB  | DataC
===============================
  1  |  10   | 'hello' | NULL
  2  |  20   | 'world' | NULL
  3  |  30   |  NULL   | NULL
  4  | NULL  |  NULL   | '2020-01-01'
```

No user has `D` enabled so it does not show up in a query

I was going to come up with a dynamic SQL that's built every time I execute the query depending on the state of `UserEnabled` but I'm afraid this is going to perform poorly on a huge data set as the execution plan will need to be created every time. I want to dynamically display only the enabled data, not columns with all NULL.

Is there another way?

Usage will be a data sheet that may be generated up to a number of times per minute.

Comment: Assuming a typo, but based on the desired results, C4 should be 1

Comment: Yes, a typo, thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because I thought this could be fun.

**Example**

```
Declare @Col varchar(max) = ''
Declare @Src varchar(max) = ''

Select @Col = @Col+','+Item+'.[Data'+Item+']'
      ,@Src = @Src+'Left Join [Table'+Item+'] '+Item+' on U.[User]=['+Item+'].[User] and U.['+Item+']=1'+char(13)
 From  (
        Select Item
         From  ( Select A=max(A)
                       ,B=max(B)
                       ,C=max(C)
                       ,D=max(D)
                  From  UserEnabled
                  Where 1=1   --<< Use any Key Inital Filter Condition Here
               ) A
         Unpivot ( value for item in (A,B,C,D)) B
         Where Value=1
       ) A

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select U.[User]'+@Col+'
From  @UserEnabled U
'+@Src

--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
User DataA  DataB   DataC
1    10     Hello   NULL
2    20     World   NULL
3    30     NULL    NULL
4    NULL   NULL    2020-01-01
```

**The Generated SQL**

```
Select A.[User],A.[DataA],B.[DataB],C.[DataC]
From  UserEnabled U
Left Join TableA A on U.[User]=[A].[User] and U.[A]=1
Left Join TableB B on U.[User]=[B].[User] and U.[B]=1
Left Join TableC C on U.[User]=[C].[User] and U.[C]=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no choice but to approach this through dynamic SQL.  A `select` query has a fixed set of columns defined when the query is created.  No such thing as "variable" columns.

What can you do?  One method is to "play a trick".  Store the columns as JSON (or XML) and delete the empty columns.

Another method is to create a view that has the specific logic you need. I think you can maintain this view by altering it in a trigger, based on when data in the enabled table changes.  That said, altering the view requires dynamic SQL so the code will not be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If all the relations are 1:1, you can make one query with

```
...
FROM u 
LEFT JOIN a ON u.id = a.u_id
LEFT JOIN b ON u.id = b.u_id
LEFT JOIN c ON u.id = c.u_id
LEFT JOIN d ON u.id = d.u_id
...
```

and use display logic on the client to omit the irrelevant columns.

If more than one relation is 1:N, then you'd likely have to do multiple queries anyway to prevent N1xN2 results.